# "ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT" " PostgreSQL error

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am new to SQL and am attempted to create a table, then alter the table to add some constraints with ALTER and finally insert 2 employees, one managing the other.
I have been getting this error in pgAdmin4 "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
If anyone could let me know any other obvious issues in my code that would be great

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE employee ( 
    emp_id     integer NOT NULL, 
    first_name varchar(15) NOT NULL, 
    last_name  varchar(15) NOT NULL, 
    manager    integer 
);
```

And the altering:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT unique_emp_id UNIQUE (emp_id);  

ALTER TABLE employee ADD FOREIGN KEY (manager) REFERENCES emp_id;

ALTER TABLE employee ADD CHECK (emp_id != manager)

INSERT INTO employee VALUES
  (1, 'Tom', 'Jones', 2);

INSERT INTO employee (emp_id, first_name, last_name)
  VALUES  (2, 'Dave', 'Smith');
```

Comment: There is a semicolon missing after the last `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key reference needs to mention the table, even for a self-reference:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD FOREIGN KEY (manager) REFERENCES employee(emp_id);
```

In addition, the first `insert` doesn't work because the table is empty, so the foreign key fails.  The `insert`s are in the wrong order.  You should also list all the columns for an `insert`, even when you think you know them.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e1880) is a SQL Fiddle with the rest of the statements working.

Comment: @JamesLindsay . . . Yes, you have to add the manager with key 2.